# What is the meaning of the word "light" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This context is from a script from the movie "The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo"

> Your report is **light** in another area.  His personal life.  Anything you chose not to include?

> 26. **light on** informal lacking a sufficient quantity of (something)

Seems like this definition fits here but there is no preposition "on" Is this the meaning here? can you use it like that?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is the same. [This entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/light), in the adjective section, meaning 18, says that "light" (the word itself) can carry the same meaning as "light on" or "short on."

*Light on* is a phrase; it can take an object by itself: "Your report was light on details." *Light in* is not really its own phrase, so much; it's really just that same meaning of "light," combined with a category. One difference in usage: We can use *light on* with the "items" that are lacking, but *light in ___* only with categories; we even sometimes turn an item into a category humorously: "My sandwich is light on the mayonnaise." "My sandwich is light in the mayonnaise department."

Comment: Andy, light on is not a phrase really. heavy on x, light on x, right on y. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

- heavy on x, light on x, right on x [that] etc.

on plus a noun or on the plus a noun means: with regard to or as regards.
This soup is heavy on salt.

BUT: light in an area, because in an area means in this subject matter.